# Create a constraint to not insert repeated values in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I´m using hibernate and wanted to know if there is one way to don´t repeate values.

I have five columns, and I and the set o this five columns value to don´t repeat for example.

```
column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 | column 5  
 apple       fruit      red         good      healthy
```

And if someone try to insert the same row value it will not save, but if one column have the value alter like

```
column 1 | column 2 | column 3 | column 4 | column 5  
strawberry    fruit      red         good      healthy
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a composite unique constraint:

```
alter table yourtable add unique index(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5);
```

Comment: Excelent, the way I wanted.

Comment: If you are using Hibernate's DDL schema generation, you can also use the uniqueConstraints attribute of the @Table annotation to have Hibernate create this unique index for you.